# Add commas as thousands separator and floating point dot in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have this

```
$example = "1234567"
$subtotal =  number_format($example, 2, '.', '');
```

the return of $subtotal is `"1234567.00"`
how to modify the definition of $subtotal, make it like this `"1,234,567.00"`

Comment: number_format($example, 2, '.', ','); will do the thing for you..

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Comment: Hint: if you want to use the separator longer than 1 character (e.g. "&nbsp;") that will not work in php < 5.4.0, unfortunately..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Below will output `1,234,567.00`

```
$example = "1234567";
$subtotal =  number_format($example, 2, '.', ',');
echo $subtotal;
```

Syntax

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

But I advise you to use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) which will formats a number as a currency string

Answer (score 3):

You have many options, but [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) can do the trick for you.

```
// Example:

$amount = '100000';
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN');
$amount = money_format('%!i', $amount);
echo $amount;

// Output:

"1,00,000.00"
```

Please note that `money_format()` is only defined if the system has `strfmon` capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so it is undefined in Windows.

Final edit: Here's a pure PHP Implementation that will work on any system:

```
$amount = '10000034000';
$amount = moneyFormatIndia( $amount );
echo number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');

function moneyFormatIndia($num){
    $explrestunits = "" ;
    if(strlen($num)>3){
        $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
        $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
        $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
        $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++){
            // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
            if($i==0){
                $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
            }else{
                $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
            }
        }
        $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
    } else {
        $thecash = $num;
    }
    return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
}
```

Comment: don't know what i have done wrong but it actually doesn't output anything. i will use the method from @Dasun instead. thanks anyway

Comment: Check it my Pure PHP Implementation

Comment: excuse me, but what does the `number_format` on third line do? Like why is it here, I read the php.net definition, still no clue. actually your function is  working fine without it, and throwing an error if I include the third line.

Answer (score 2):

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

```
string money_format ( string $format , float $number )
```

ex:

```
// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

**Note:** The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

**Note:** The LC_MONETARY category of the locale settings, affects the behavior of this function. Use setlocale() to set to the appropriate default locale before using this function.

Use **number_format** : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )

$number        = 123457;
$format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
// 1,234.57
```

Comment: I don't know what i have done wrong but it actually doesn't output anything. i will use the method from @Dasun instead. thanks anyway

Comment: @LionLiu : money_format will not work with the windows, I updated the answer please check it.